# How to connect $scope.current_youser.name to textbox

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

This is my json

```
{name: "Macey Moon", age: 26}
```

When i click on a name , i go to the update page , that's where i update info.

I have a problem with this function **bake_him(y)**.  
I can't connect **$scope.current_youser.name** with my nicename textbox. 
Same with **$scope.current_youser.id**

```
Your nice name <input ng-model="current_youser.name"/>
```

What's wrong with my code?
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKKdzR?editors=101

Comment: If you have a problem with the function `bake_him(y)` please add the code for that function to your question.

Comment: oh yeah, its very long. better keep it in my codepen.

Comment: Yes, that's a really long function (I broke down and looked). There was one line of actual code, and like 5 `console.log` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you have multiple `ng-controller="pet_ctrl"`. And every `ng-controller` statement creates it's own scope. So, you update one scope and then try to read from another.

Try to use `ng-controller="pet_ctrl"` just one time here. For example, i've tried something like this - wrap all your html to div with ng-controller directive and delete other `ng-controller="pet_ctrl"`

```
<div ng-controller="pet_ctrl">
  <ons-tabbar var = "cheese" >
    <ons-tab page="list.love" active="true"  label = "All" icon = "ion-home"  >
      </ons-tab>

      ...

    </div>
  </ons-template>
</div>
```